# Can't get image from nao_camera

Tags: nao-robot, nao, nao-driver, image-view, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want some help.

I am using NAO right now. I follow this tutorial : [www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started)

and I can make it walk, etc.

INFO : I am using this version -> pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.12.5-linux64

But, I need the image from NAO camera.

So, in the nao_driver, I add this :

```
<node pkg="nao_driver" type="nao_camera.py" name="nao_camera" required="true" args="--pip=$(arg nao_ip) --pport=$(arg nao_port)" output="screen"/>
```

Then I run :

```
rostopic list -v
```

Result :

```
zangetsu@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ rostopic list -v

Published topics:
 * /image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 6 publishers
 * /joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState] 1 publisher
... etc ...
```

and ROS said the /image_raw topic is there.

But when I run this :

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/image_raw
```

Nothing happens, just a gray screen in the frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66400/can%27t-get-image-from-nao_camera/) by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-02**:
No idea, but just a comment: You could also try reporting the problems (& wishes) at the [ROS/Nao mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran)

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-07-02**:
Is there anyone who success run it before ?

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-07-02**:
btw, I got this error when I try execute :

> rostopic echo /image_raw

WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-02**:
Why do you have the sim time parameter enabled, are you playing back from a bag file? Are you using "--clock" with "rosbag play"?

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-07-02**:
no, I connect it directly to NAO. I didn't use rosbag. I am using the real robot.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-02**:
Well, something set "/use_sim_time" to True, it needs to be False

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-07-02**:
hmm I check with rosparam get use_sim_time, the result is false ...

@AHornung but when I try to run it manually with this script

http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/_downloads/videoInput_getImage.py

it stuck at this line :
nameId = camProxy.subscribe("python_GVM", resolution,

**Comment by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) on 2014-06-04**:
I have similar issue, I can't launch the process because it's dying in the middle of the launch, I have managed to get to know, and it's dying at the same line camProxy.subscribe("rospy_gvm", self.resolution, self.colorSpace, self.fps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, actually today I can retrieve image from nao_camera ... and I don't know why yesterday they just give me a gray image either ROS or the NaoQI (via python).

But, I can retrieve it "after" I open monitor software (in the same folder as Choreograph).

So, for the one who has got same problem with me. Maybe you can try to launch Monitor software and click Play button. After that mine is fixed.

---

Originally posted by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) with karma: 18 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-07-03**:
do you use the old version of the NAO head? Maybe it is necessary to "select" one camera before the topics are produced (The old NAO can just use one camera at a time).